# How to replace exact matching strings only with using 2 replace

Tags: c#

I am trying to replace string but due to few matching words it is replacing both the string.

```
Val1 = "CASE WHEN [" + isParent + "] = 0 THEN 'False' WHEN [" + isParent + "] = 1 THEN 'True' END ";
Val2 = "CASE WHEN [" + isChild + "] = 0 THEN 'False' WHEN [" + isChild  + "] = 1 THEN 'True' END ";
val3 = str.Replace("IS_PARENT", Val1 ).Replace("IS_CHILD", val2);
```

in my

```
str = "IS_PARENT, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, IS_CHILD";
```

IS_CHILD is coming in two place so it is replacing both IS_CHILD.

I want to replace only exact word IS_CHILD.

how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Regex.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwewhkd1.aspx)

```
string newString = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bIS_CHILD\b", replacedText);
```

EDIT: 
If you want to replace IS_PARENT with the same criteria as IS_CHILD *(replacing the whole word only)*

```
string  newString = Regex.Replace(newString, @"\bIS_PARENT\b", "NEW TEXT");
newString = Regex.Replace(str, @"\bIS_CHILD\b", replacedText);
```

<strike>OR</strike>  *(This is not optimized and in the answer because it is one way to replace a single word)*

You can split the string based on the space, and then use string.Join to create a new string after replacing the complete word.

```
string str = "IS_PARENT, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, IS_CHILD";
string replacedText = "SomeThing";
string newString = string.Join(" ", str.Split()
                                       .Select(r => r == "IS_CHILD" ? replacedText : r));
```

New String will be:

```
IS_PARENT, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, SomeThing
```

Comment: The same exact functionality could be achieved with replacing " IS CHILD" with " SomeThing" (with spaces at the start of the string).

Comment: @DariuszWawer, yup, that is why Just added Regex.Replace

Comment: I want to replace IS_PARENT and IS_CHILD at the same time from the str, will you please check again my qus. that is the reason I am using 2 replace

Comment: @Habib: Shukriya, it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using regular expressions within an extension method to preserve same syntax style:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static string ReplaceExact(this string value, 
                                      string oldWord, string newWord)
    {
        Regex r = new Regex(string.Format(@"\b{0}\b", oldWord));
        return r.Replace(value, newWord);
    }
}
```

and use it:

```
string str = "IS_CHILD, IS_CHILD ,IS_CHILD, IS_PARENT, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, IS_CHILD";
string result = str.ReplaceExact("IS_CHILD", "000")
                   .ReplaceExact("IS_PARENT", "111");
Console.WriteLine(result); 
//prints: 000, 000 ,000, 111, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, 000
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is using Regex:

```
val3 = Regex.Replace(Regex.Replace(str, @"\bIS_PARENT\b", Val1), @"\bIS_CHILD\b", Val2);
```

Answer (score 1):

A very simple way to do this would be:

```
val3 = str.Replace("IS_PARENT", Val1 ).Replace(", IS_CHILD", ", "+val2);
```

but in that case, why wouldn't you just do:

```
val3 = val1 + ", IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, " + val2;
```

where is str coming from?

Answer (score 0):

Use [LastIndexOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-en/library/system.string.lastindexof.aspx), cut the string manually and insert the replacement at a correct place. Like this:

```
Val1 = "CASE WHEN [" + isParent + "] = 0 THEN 'False' WHEN [" + isParent + "] = 1 THEN 'True' END ";
Val2 = "CASE WHEN [" + isChild + "] = 0 THEN 'False' WHEN [" + isChild  + "] = 1 THEN 'True' END ";
ReplaceLast(str, "IS_PARENT", Val1 );
ReplaceLast(str, "IS_CHILD", Val2 );

public static string ReplaceLast(this string value, 
                                      string oldWord, string newWord)
{
    int index = value.LastIndexOf(oldWord);
    String modified = value.Remove(index, oldWord.Length);
    modified = modified.Insert(index, newWord);
    return modified;
}
```

It is probably the least processing power and memory consuming method of doing what you need in this situation. It is also the most low-level.

Comment: You should elaborate in greater detail for this to be worth an answer, not a comment

Answer (score 0):

May be this could help

```
string child = "IS_PARENT, IS_CHILD_WITH_ROLE, IS_CHILD", 
       resultString = string.Empty;

List<string> chunks = child.Split(' ').ToList();
chunks.ForEach(delegate(string i)
{
   if (string.Equals(i, "IS_CHILD", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
      resultString += "ReplaceString ";
   else
      resultString += i + " ";
});

Console.WriteLine(child);
Console.WriteLine(resultString);

Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use like this Body.Replace("\bat\b", "at")